# How to keep certain processes in a multiprocessing.Pool() from printing to stdout in Python?

Tags: python

Right now I have the following situation:

```
    def take_time(time):
        sleep(time)
        print("Took %d seconds!" %time)

   def multip(num_cores, data):
       p = multiprocessing.Pool(num_cores)
       p.map(take_time, data)
       end_time = time()
       print("total time taken: %d" %(end_time - start_time))
```

Suppose `num_cores = 2` and `data = (1,1,3)`.

```
>>> multi(4, data)
Took 1 seconds!
Took 1 seconds!
Took 3 seconds!
```

How can this be rendered so that only one process goes to stdout at a time? 
It does not particularly matter which process is being printed, so long as no two print simultaneously. Suppose we let the process corresponding to `data[1]` print at first. Then, the desired output would be

```
>>> multi(4, data)
Took 1 seconds!
Took 3 seconds!
```

I'm guessing there is just a a more fine-toothed tool than `map()`. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you expecting to get only two outputs if you have three inputs?

Comment: Instead of printing from within `take_time` you could return a value to your main thread/process and have that print it sequentially there.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is to write from only one running thread, and have your other threads output to a queue. Doing this requires that your main thread initiate the others asynchronously (using for example, [map_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async)), and then read from the queue until they are done. Taking your example, you would do something like this:

```
q = multiprocessing.Queue()

def take_time(time):
    sleep(time)
    q.put("Took %d seconds!" %time)

def multip(num_cores, data):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(num_cores)
    start_time = time()
    result = p.map_async(take_time, data)

    while not result.ready():
        print q.get()

    end_time = time()
    print("total time taken: %d" %(end_time - start_time))
```

For a real-world example of how this can be applied, [check out the code](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/c8daf17db6ea7a180d622c7c9e6bae15751635af/compose/cli/log_printer.py#L74-L105) for the `docker-compose log` command, which reads the output of potentially multiple containerized processes and combines them into a single stream.

Comment: Note: Just using `imap` or `imap_unordered` would simplify this; make the return value the string to print, and you don't need to manage the `Queue` yourself. `for result in p.imap_unordered(take_time, data): print(result)`, and change the `q.put` to `return "Took %d seconds!" % time`

Comment: Thats true- using a queue solves the general case where threads produce 0 or more output strings over a period of time but could be overkill if you just need to print at the end of execution and can get by with a `return`.